# Синхронизация данных клиентов с сервером

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Делаю распределенное приложение на андроиде. Есть некоторое количество клиентов, сервер и БД. Смысл такой, что, например, с одного клиента я добавляю/удаляю/обновляю в БД некоторую запись и мне необходимо сделать так, что бы эта запись отобразилась на всех приложениях установленных на устройствах.
Будьте добры, подскажите, что мне нужно использовать что бы реализовать это дело. Собственно интересно следующее:
0) На чем писать сервер?
1) Где хранить БД и сам файл написанного сервера, что бы можно было к нему подключиться **удаленно**?
2) В данном случае юзать REST API или JSON?
3) Как обновлять данные на приложениях других устройств, после того, как из одного устройства были добавлены/изменены/удалены данные?
4) Если приложение свернуто (работает в фоновом режиме), как отобразит уведомление, что была добавлена/удалена/обновлена запись?
Возможно прозвучали глупые вопросы - прошу вникнуть в положение. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в вашем случае необходимо использовать `веб-сокеты`

Comment: @jashka, да, спасибо, как раз о них тоже читал. Но все же, вопросы остаются те же. Не совсем понятно, что использовать и как хранить.

Answer (score 1):

1. ) Сервер можете написать на чем угодно. Это зависит от того какой язык вы знаете. Если знаете `java`, то и пишите на ней. Есть `Spring`, `Play`, `JSF`.
2. ) Базу хранить на сервере
3. ) Можете использовать для передачи данных `JSON` или `XML`.
4. ) По сути если будет какая-то реакция (добавление/удаление/редактирование), клиент при подключении до сервера с веб сокетами подписывается на события, а на клиенте вы уже обрабатываете полученное событие с данными.
5. ) Некомпетентный в этом вопросе.

Comment: А если использовать пример этой статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/269135/? Но я так понимаю, здесь не использованы сокеты.

Comment: @Tomas там для того что бы узнать пришло ли сообщение, каждые 15 секунд слали запрос на сервер (плохо для вашего телефона, заряд аккамулятора улетучится быстро), вместо этого можно было использовать `longpolling`, `push notification`

Comment: Т.е. смотрите, если с самого нуля, тогда мне тогда понадобится установить сервер, например, Jetty подойдет?

Comment: @Tomas пойдет, я вам написал в общем, если что-то спросите по `java`, я могу не ответить

Comment: Я понял. Можете кинуть пару ссылок, что бы наглядно понять с чем придется иметь дело?

Comment: `jetty websokcet server` - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-websocket-server-api.html . Так же там есть и `jetty websocket client`

Comment: А он будет дружить с MySQL и не будет проблем с доступом клиентов, если я поставлю Jetty к себе на ПК?

Comment: @Tomas будет, вот https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource

Comment: Спасибо! А при обращении к моему сервер-сокету на Jetty, как обратиться правильно к нему? Т.к. у меня ведь все по локалхосту работает по-умолчанию.